# How to run a scheduled task at specific times?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I need to run a scheduled task every day at 9 a.m. and 6 p.m. How can I do this? I looked into `PeriodicTask` but it runs once every 30 mins. How do I achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. However, you can check if the time is close to 9am/6pm when the Scheduled Task is running every 30 minutes. The furthest off you'll get is 29 minutes.

Consider using a [Reminder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at Reminders, Its somewhat similar to Windows Phone system Reminders. What I wanted to do is to post some values to a HTTP URL and change application state to close/open based on the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the scheduled notification of Alarm in windows phone os7.1.

check here:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202946(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202946%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)